# Views: How to list nodes that are referencing to nodes, pointing to the current node

Tags: views, entities

I have 3 contenttypes where 2 of them have reference entity fields. Each their own entityfield.

Contenttype C is the parent. Type B points to type C. Type A points to B.

On every Node of type C i want to display a view that lists the nodes of type A pointing to B, that points to C. Is this possible?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this overview https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004 it only uses two content types but a third could be thrown in there. It's a little tricky to get setup at first but works pretty well. Although it may not work since you have C->B->A but may be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view that filters C nodes. Go to view advanced options and add a relationship with the field in B which references A and choose Referencing entity. Give a name name "children" to this relationship. Then create another relationship based on the field in A that references B. For this relationship use the previous relationship. Name this one grandchildren. Last add fields you need from the A nodes and dont forget to use relationship grandchildren for each one.

Alternatively use node A as base table and use the referring entity relationship type. Now you want to check require relationship to emulate an inner sql join and thus filter out B and C nodes with no references

Answer (score 0):

I can't easily think of a way offhand. I see 2 options. I would try option 2 first (it's a bit easier).

1. Try to use the [Relation](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) module and attached fields to
   relation(s) and use the Relations within Views.
2. Another option I did for something similar is use [Computed
   Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) to store meta-data I needed to make Views reporting a little easier. For example in your scenario I might add a
   Computed Field on `Node Type C` that stores a list of related Node Ids in a comma
   seperated list like: `"234,543,875"`. You would write `custom PHP code` that could use an `EntityFieldQuery` to find the NIDs of the related content you want and save that list as a string of IDs. Then you could add a field of [Views
   Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field) on Node Type C that renders a View of related content that
   passes as an argument the NID list as a `token` from the computed field.

Your example (lists of related, related things) is something I always find tricky to do -- through trial and error I have come to see trying to add meta-data to my relationships (like option 1 or 2 above) make working with the data easier.